# Check image in folder and display image if exists or display default image using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I need to display user profile image.
but from DB, i dont have any field for image. so I get it using UserId in one folder.
Now If i display one user details, I need to display user profile image from folder using UserId using angularjs.

if image not available, need to display default image.

I need to do this using anglarjs.
I am getting user details through LoggedUser details from angular controller.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How about you show us the code you have so far and why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is very simple:

If image is null or '', change default image link.

eg:

```
    $scope.defaultImageUrl = 'any url...';
    if ( !$scope.LoggedUser.profileImage || $scope.LoggedUser.profileImage === '' ) {
      $scope.LoggedUser.profileImage = $scope.defaultImageUrl;
    }
```

Same solution without controller statement:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{ LoggedUser.profileImage || defaultImageUrl }}">
```

**Solution with $http module.**

- Set profileImage to false.
- Set url of default image.
- Send get request to the unique user image.
- If request is success, set url to profileimage, otherwise log error.

```js
$scope.LoggedUser.profileImage = false;
$scope.profileImageUrl = 'content/images/'+$scope.LoggedUser.userid+'.jpg';
$http.get( $scope.profileImageUrl )
.then( function() {
    $scope.LoggedUser.profileImage = $scope.profileImageUrl;
  }, function( error ) {
    console.log( 'image error: ', error );
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, actually, I am accessing the image using UserId. for example, content/images/121.jpg. in this, 121 is user id. so I am trying to accessing this as content/images/{{loggeduser.userid}}.jpg. these all correct, now i want to check that images folder contains that image(121.jpg) or not, if not, i want to display default image.

Comment: I see. I will send new solution tomorrow.

Comment: Hi jozsef, thanks for updated solution, actually, it doesn't search in folder (content/images), it always return 406 not acceptable response. please look at what i have tried in my code. var profilepic = '/content/images/' + vm.userDetails.UserGuid + '.jpg';
        $http.get(profilepic)
.then(function () {
    vm.profileImage = profilepic;
}, function (error) {
    console.log('image error: ', error);
    vm.profileImage = '/content/images/profile.jpg';
}
);

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution to display default image if src image not found in directory.

```
angular.module("Test").directive('errSrc', function ($q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function (ngSrc) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var image = new Image();
                image.onerror = function () {
                    deferred.resolve(false);
                    element.attr('src', '/content/images/ProfileImages/profile.png'); // set default image
                };
                image.onload = function () {
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                };
                image.src = ngSrc;
                return deferred.promise;
            });
        }
    };
});

in View:
  <img ng-src="/content/images/ProfileImages/{{vm.userDetails.UserGuid}}.jpg" err-src alt="" width="60%">
```

Thanks once again who are all help me to solve this.